# Why is a std::set slower in traversing all the elements?

Tags: c++, stl, set

We have a code that was originally using a deque as a container. Unfortunately, it wasn't fast enough for our time measurements since it's taking quite some time for it to do a search or sort. So, I recently refactored the code to try and use a set instead. It's definitely faster in terms of searching and sorting than a deque.

One thing I noticed though is that the set was way slower when traversing all the elements. We have a test that basically just traverses the elements from beginning up to the end until it matches the values it is looking for and found out that the set is taking almost 5x the time it takes for the deque to do it.

Can someone provide an explanation as to why the set is slower? I assumed that the time would be around the same since it's simply a traversal of all the elements from start to end, but that's not the case. I already did a lot of searching but can't find anything about a set being slower in traversing its elements.

Update: The set/deque contains a class that basically has two integer member variables.

```
class Element
{
    uint32_t id;
    uint32_t time;
};

Compile options:
-g -pipe -funit-at-a-time
-O3 --param inline-unit-growth=10000 --param large-function-growth=10000 --param max-inline-insns-single=10000
-Wall -Wextra -Wno-aggregate-return -Wno-padded -Wno-reorder -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wdisabled-optimization -Wfloat-equal -Wno-inline -Wlarger-than-10000 -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wpointer-arith -Wredundant-decls -Wno-unknown-pragmas
```

Comment: *We have a test that basically just traverses the elements from beginning up to the end until it matches the values it is looking for* Can you use `std::set::find` instead?

Comment: We do have a test using std::set::find and it's working ok. The traversal from beginning to end was explicitly done as part of a different test.

Comment: I am not talking about using `std::find`. I am talking about using `std::set::find`.

Comment: Sorry, misread that one. I updated my reply.

Comment: It's likely that a `dequeue` stores most of its contents sequentially in memory, making it a very cache-friendly structure (for iteration).  A `set`, OTOH, may well be storing each item in the set at a different/arbitrary location in memory, which would mean that there is little or no locality-of-reference during a set-traversal, and therefore your CPUs' caches are not as effective at hiding the RAM subsystem's inherent latency during a set-traversal as they were during a dequeue-traversal.

Comment: @thedandyman Please post the compiler options you used to build your test program.  If you're running an unoptimized or "debug" build, your findings are basically meaningless.

Comment: are you storing Element* in your set, or are you storing Element itself? That can make a huge difference.

For cache performance, think of using placement new for your class object.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie added the compile options but I think it's already optimized and not in debug mode.

Comment: @Pranay I tried both already. The pointer version was actually worse.

Comment: @thedandyman -- The `set`'s strength is not traversing, it is searching / insertion / deletion.

Comment: Can you tell me if you're also including the time it takes to create the objects? or is it just the traversal that you benchmark. 
I am confirming because insertion is O(ln) for set and O(1). That can make this difference if you also include the creation. 
I find it hard to believe that set won't perform because a set has access to the next pointer.

Comment: @Pranay- the creation/ insertion of elements in the set is not included in the benchmarking, only the traversal itself.

Comment: Each element in the set is a separate allocation  ; traversing the set involves walking up and down pointer chains;  whereas traversing a deque just means incrementing a pointer most of the time, and occasionally jumping to a new block

Comment: I did the benchmark exercise by diffing times over large loops. You're right.
Then I made a small enhancement. I started saving everything in a deque and then had a set store the pointers to the deque iterator.
This gave me a fast traversal as well as find.
It does complicate all the operations but it is a one time effort. If linear traversal is a requirement, use this to get best of both.
You need to provide a set comparator, which should be trivial for most things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two aspects in set traversal that are more difficult than in list traversal. The cache locality, as explained in the comments and the necessity to store a state to the iterator.

The sets are often implemented as self-balancing trees -- because generating a binary tree from sorted data would produce a degenerate tree, a linked list, which would not allow O(log N) insertions, deletions, or find.
The self-balancing property will lead nodes allocated (possibly but not necessarily) from adjacent memory addresses to be accessed in arbitrary order leading to more cache misses.

The other issue is that traversing a tree with an iterator requires a state machine to be encoded in the iterator -- advancing the iterator needs to know, whether to move next to the left child or to the right one, leading to also increased number of branch predictions.

Answer (score 0):

ADD:
binary tree is indeed anti-cache-friendly, but I guess it is not the main problem.
.........................
dequeue::iterator++ is just (index++)%size (implemented on array), or take its next pointer(implemented on linked list).
set::iterator++ is INORDER TRAVERSAL in a tree. imagine current position is at root's precursor, so the next is root.  it should go up and verify whether the current node is a left child, until it is,  and the root is parent of the current node.
So travsersal in dequeue is more trivial than traversal in set.
...........................
std::set is implemented based on RB-Tree(a kind of BST).
find()  is implemented with awareness of BST, which is O(logn).
If you traverse from the left-most to right-most to find the element,  the cost is O(n).
Traversal from begin() to end() is actually the InOrder Traversal of the RB-Tree, while find() just goes down from root and compare key with two children.

Comment: find() would, of course, be faster than traversal from beginning to end but that's not the question. The question is why a set is slower in traversing the elements than a deque.

Comment: traversal in set is INORDER TRAVERSAL in a tree, but traversal in dequeue is just cursor++(implemented on array) or take its next pointer(implemented on linked list)